# How to setup 2 nodes on elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

**Hello enthusiastic people.**

I am a student trying to learn Elastic stack.
I have 1 node installed on my local machine. I have also successfully installed beats on my other local machine to get data and deliver it to my logstash.

My question is, what if I add another node, do I still need to install kibana and elasticsearch? Then connect it from my first node?
I just read a lot that a single node is prone to data loss.
Sorry for my noob question.
Your answer is very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Having a cluster with at least 3 nodes would be good to ensure data security and integrity.
A cluster can have one or more nodes.

An example scenario:

[image: Elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes]

It will be easier for you to install with docker during the learning and development process. I recommend you follow the link below. This link explains how to set up an elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes on docker.

[Start a multi-node cluster with Docker Compose](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file)